# Avoid crash in recursive Dynamic

Tags: dynamic, bugs, recursion, crash

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier, persisting through 13.2 or later**

---

With the following `Dynamic` cell, I can reproducibly crash Mathematica, so do not try this unless you have saved all your work!

```
l=1;
Dynamic[Sin[l = l + 1]]
```

This will harmlessly run forever, or **until** you try to *right-click* on the dynamic output (to get the context menu and perhaps to copy the current value). When you right-click on it, Mathematica crashes.

Is there a simple way to avoid or catch this error before it occurs?

**Edit**

I also see this crash when literally using the example from the documentation for `Dynamic` (under "Applications"):

```
{Trigger[Dynamic[x, (a = FractionalPart[#]; x = Round[#]) &], {0, 
   Infinity}], 
 Dynamic[{Quotient[x, 60], Mod[x, 60], SetPrecision[10 a, 2]}]}
```

and again trying to right-click. So it's not like I'm doing something outlandish here.

**Edit 2**
The link Szabolcs found does indeed answer my question:

```
EventHandler[Dynamic[Sin[l = l + 1]], {"MouseUp", 2} :> Null]
```

seems to prevent the crash.

Comment: You should definitely report the crash to WRI.

Comment: You'll be interested in this: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/v9mlhlc2m4c/discussion

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks, that must be the same error, and the fix works. Do you want to post this as an answer?

Comment: I can't reproduce it on V9. I'll try later on 9.0.1.0.

Comment: @Kuba, yes, I think this was fixed in the meantime - I don't  see the crash on 9.0.1 anymore. But in [your question here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44697/245), the fix seems to work.

Comment: @Jens Because it captures the event, we don't want that, `FlipView` is not receiving this information so it's not working too, and `PassEventsDown` enables the bug again.

Comment: Absolutely, for your application this isn't going to work.

Comment: @Jens I'd like to add the bug header for the bugfix version. Do you recall the version for which you reported the bug? I guess for 8.0 but perhaps for an earlier version?

Comment: @Xavier If you update many posts at once, they flood the top of the stack and it makes it more difficult to find new or truly updated questions. I appreciate you going through and checking all these bugs, but I also find too many such edits discourages me from participating on the site. It's up to you and I bear no ill will, but I thought you might like know.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I understand, apologies for the flood. I will make the updates on small groups of posts from now on.

Comment: @Xavier Thanks, both for understanding and for updating the headers. :)

Comment: @Xavier Yes, I think this was for 8.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this MathGroup post describing a similar crash](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/v9mlhlc2m4c/discussion), the right click can be caught and discarded like this:

```
l = 1;
EventHandler[Dynamic[Sin[l = l + 1]], {"MouseUp", 2} :> Null]
```

This won't let you copy the value, but it will prevent crashes due to accidental right clicks.

You can obtain the value by evaluating `l` as a different input.