# FlipView can't handle CurrentValue["MouseOver"]. Kernel crash

Tags: functions, dynamic, bugs, gui-construction

**Bug introduced in V9 or earlier and fixed in V10.0.2**

Is this code crashing your Mathematica session? (*it can so look out :P*)

```
DynamicModule[{a = 1},

 FlipView[{
   Framed["(", Background -> Dynamic[If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Blue, LightBlue]]],
   Framed["<", Background -> Dynamic[If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], Blue, LightBlue]]]
   }, a]

 ]
```

> [image]

Fast workaround would be to take `Framed` outside `FlipView`. I'm just curious if this happens to all of you and if it should be marked as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: yes, at first sight! :-) crash!!

Comment: crashes when clicking on it, mma 9.0.1 on Windows 7 64bit, please report as a bug...

Comment: @AlbertRetey done.

Comment: yep, also on OSX 10.8.5 (Mathematica 9.0.1) it crashes

Comment: Perhaps related: [Avoid crash in recursive Dynamic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2018/245). The fix there *does* seem to work here if it wraps `Framed`.

Comment: The `EventHandler` workaround from the linked answer doesn't really work here. I accidentally got it to "work" with the wrong syntax: `FlipView[{EventHandler[Framed[...],Framed[...], {"MouseUp",2}:>Null]}]` which strangely produced neither an error message nor a crash. But wrapping `Framed` individually doesn't prevent the crash.

Comment: Fixed for 10.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fixed for 10.0.2. –  John Fultz 5 hours ago